# It's Taking Forever to Download a Website With Httrack

Tags: html, download, database-mirroring

I am using httrack to download this website: http://4minutearticles.com/

It's taking forever, over 1500 files counted now.

How can it be? That website is so simple, how can there be over 1500 files in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably all linked files (a, link, script, img, object).
are there multiple occurrences of same content?

check the depth of the downloads, and if it's always in the same domain.

Comment: There is a folder called 4minutearticles.com inside.
Does that means it's duplicate?

I am using the download all files +question

Comment: Now it's over 3000 files count

Comment: i don't khnow htttrack... but there's probably one issue like the ones i mentionned... ues a tool you khows! ( for instance grep will do that quick for you... or some good webscrapers ).